# ZFS package (zfs-ubuntu) does not create zfs module?

Tags: zfs, dkms

I'm trying to use ZFS (zfsforlinux stable) on Ubuntu 12.04 x86_64 Server. I enabled the PPA, and `apt-get install ubuntu-zfs` works successfully. However, no zfs module is created and the `zpool` and related commands all complain that they can't install the module.

Help!

Answer (score 4):

Install the pre-requisites and then do a

`apt-get install --reinstall zfs-dkms`

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend editing this answer to explain in greater detail what the prerequisites are and how to install them.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not have build-essentials and kernel header installed the DKMS build steps will fail during the install of `ubuntu-zfs`.  Were any error messages written to the console?

I ran into a similar problem.  I attempted to install `ubuntu-zfs` BEFORE installing `build-essentials` and the kernel headers.  That left a bit of a mess.  Removing `ubuntu-zfs` does not remove all of it's dependencies.  I had to:

```
dpkg --list | grep zfs
```

and

```
dpkg --list | grep spl
```

and track down the packages that were not removed by apt-get purge ubuntu-zfs.

After cleaning things up and installing the correct pre-requisites the install worked but still failed to correctly configure the modules to load.

Comment: I had the same issue.  To be a bit more clear do the following:

**apt-get remove --purge ubuntu-zfs zfs-dkms zfsutils spl spl-dkms libzfs1 dkms**

Then, **REBOOT**.  Then, do:
**apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential**

Then, do:
**apt-get install ubuntu-zfs**